# Add a row to the bottom of a table inserting the column header as its content - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery mobiile app which has hundreds of tables included within it. I'd like to be able to add a new row to the end of each of these tables which would include a cell with a button contained within it with a "data-"attribute derived directly from the table header of that table.

I've managed to add a row, and a "test" value to each but I'm completely at a loss as to how to get the column header to display in the bottom cell.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>michael</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jeff</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>david</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>juan</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

and the script...

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.siblings(':first-child').text(),
        pos = $this.index() + 1,
        num = $this.parent().siblings().first().children(':nth-child('+pos+')').text();        
    alert(num + ' & ' + name);
});

// appends a row to the bottom of the tables for Add to Cart Button 
$('table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr class="cartRow"></tr>');

// Selects each of the th cells
$('table > tbody > tr ').find('th').each(function() {
    // appends a cell to the row  
    $('table > tbody > tr:last-child').append('<td class="cartButton">'. value . '</td>');
});

// adds the button content to the table cell
$('.cartButton').append("test");
```

Comment: Before I submit an answer, are you trying to "move" the column header to the bottom of each table? Or are you wanting to have a header column both on top and on the bottom of each table?

Comment: Hi Fictus, Thanks for replying. Basically, I need to add a button at the bottom of each of the columns, using the content of the <th> to  add  to the data-name="" attribute of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterating over `th` and appending its content use, `$(this).text()`,

```
// Selects each of the th cells
$('table > tbody > tr > th').each(function() {
    // appends a cell to the row  
    $('table > tbody > tr:last-child')
      .append('<td class="cartButton">'+$(this).text()+'</td>');
});
```

---

Another change would be, remove `:last-child`, it won't make any difference. Append anyways adds for last child.

```
$('table > tbody:last-child').append(..
```

```js
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.siblings(':first-child').text(),
        pos = $this.index() + 1,
        num = $this.parent().siblings().first().children(':nth-child('+pos+')').text();        
    alert(num + ' & ' + name);
});

// appends a row to the bottom of the tables for Add to Cart Button 
$('table > tbody').append('<tr class="cartRow"></tr>');

// Selects each of the th cells
$('table > tbody > tr > th').each(function() {
    // appends a cell to the row  
    $('table > tbody > tr:last-child')
      .append('<td class="cartButton">'+$(this).text()+'</td>');
});

// adds the button content to the table cell
$('.cartButton').append("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>michael</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jeff</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>david</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>juan</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

For adding a new row at end of each table :

```
// Selects each of the th cells
$('table').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('tbody > tr > th', this).each(function(){
        // appends a cell to the row  
        $('tbody > tr:last-child', $this)
          .append('<td class="cartButton">'+$(this).text()+'</td>');
    });
});
```

```js
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.siblings(':first-child').text(),
        pos = $this.index() + 1,
        num = $this.parent().siblings().first().children(':nth-child('+pos+')').text();        
    alert(num + ' & ' + name);
});

// appends a row to the bottom of the tables for Add to Cart Button 
$('table > tbody').append('<tr class="cartRow"></tr>');

// Selects each of the th cells
$('table').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('tbody > tr > th', this).each(function(){
        // appends a cell to the row  
        $('tbody > tr:last-child', $this)
          .append('<td class="cartButton">'+$(this).text()+'</td>');
    });
});

// adds the button content to the table cell
$('.cartButton').append("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>michael</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jeff</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>david</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>juan</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, This was so close to being perfect. Now it just seems to adding a new cell for every table in the dom on each table rather than just the table directly being related too. Ideally I'd like to be able to add this without adding any ID's to each table.

See this jfiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/chrisburnsdesign/87su7kyq/31/

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by *table viewing*.

Comment: So say we have 2 tables in the document each with 4 columns. On each of those tables it seems to be adding 8 <td>'s rather than just the 4 per table.

Comment: I think you did not use my latest code. Please check bottom of my answer

Comment: Perfecto. Fantastic. Thank you so much, you've just saved me a massive headache!

Answer (score 0):

Clone first row to the end?
And add button according to attributes?

```js
$('table').each(function(){
  $(this).find('tr:first').clone().appendTo(this)
  .find('th:not(:nth-child(1))').each(function(){
    $('<button/>').html($(this).attr('id'))// use .data(...) if need
    .appendTo($(this).html(''))
  })
})
```

```css
table,tr,td,th{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>         <th id="a">1</th> <th id="b">2</th> <th id="c">3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>michael</td>   <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jeff</td>      <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>david</td>     <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>juan</td>      <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```